# R: How to compare a pair of single-element lists without loop

Tags: r

This should be simple, but a limitiation with lapply (or at least in the way I understand to implement lapply) is only being allowed to pass a single list as the first argument.  Here is a toy example of what I am trying to do:

```
a = list(1, 2, 3)
b = list(3, 2, 1)

a > b
```

What I want as output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

which, through unlist(), I will convert to

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Of course, you cannot do it using a > b, so instead, I get:

```
Error in a > b : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

What is the most elegant way to compare these lists without resorting to loops, which will yield an output similar to what I a looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: `Map(">", a, b)` OR `mapply(">", a, b)`

Comment: `unlist(a) > unlist(b)` gives the final desired result

Comment: Do you really want to store these numbers in a list and not a simple atomic vector? Seems like an odd way to store the data.

Comment: No, I want atomic vector, just assumed I would end up with a list that I would coerce with unlist().

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew it would be a simple answer!